# before filter lambda wrong number of arguments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I am playing around with some old projects, trying to use modules in controllers.

I have a before_action filter in the controller which passes through an argument.

```
 include CrudConcern
  before_action lambda { index(Test.all) }, only: :index
```

and in the module

```
  def index(model)
    var_name = "@#{model.name.downcase.pluralize}"
    self.instance_variable_set(var_name, model)
  end
```

However I am encounytering this error... Not sure why.

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I am passing the expected number of arguments so not sure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the method name from index to something else. If you have an index action in your controller, it might be trying to call that instead of the index method in your module.